# Gamecenter works in sandbox, but not when testing using promo code

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, sandbox, game-center, leaderboard

I am having some issues with gamecenter. 
When the player tries to connect to gamecenter, an error message is shown in the application. None of the leader boards are showing up either.

> Error 15 Error Domain=GKErrorDomain Code=15 "The requested operation
>   could not be completed because this application is not recognized by
>   Game Center.

The app isn't actually released, I am testing the "live" version using a promo code.
Is this to be expected? Will everything work fine once I actually release the app?

- Everything works fine when I am compiling through xcode or testing an ad hock version in sandbox.
- Gamecenter leaderboards where activated and included with the version I submitted to the app store for this release
- The leaderboards for this app are displayed as "live" in iTunes connect

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it.
When an app has been approved, but the developer has set to "manually release the app", this issue is active.

The solution was to press the "release" button in iTunes connect.

I'd like to release the app next week, so I set the availability date for next Thursday, that seem to solve the issue without actually releasing the app publicly.